# Kindle docs not available for transfer

Tags: filemanager, kindle

I have Kindle 7th generation with firmwarw 5.12.2.2, and I had it for years. Recently battery is dying fast, so I wanted to buy new one.
BUT
I have over 350 files I transferred to kindle via usb (simple explorer), I don't have copies any where else (dumb, I know) . The problem is now that I try to get them to PC via usb again they're not there. Amd everything in the cloud is what I've bought in Amazon only (which is about 14 books only).

How do I get access so that I can move them to new kindle? (dimm

Comment: Are you using the right cable? If Kindle doesn't appear on your PC, it's either you have the wrong/not working cable or there is problem with your kindle's output port. fyi, there are two types of USB cables; one type only supports charging and the other supports charging as well as data transfer.

Comment: Kindle appears, but none of my previously uploaded files do. I can see them on Kindle, read them, make notes etc but on cable, on cloud or pc app they don't appeae

Comment: are you able to provide a screenshot of the the folders in your Kindle after you connected it to your pc? The files shouldn't be missing unless they are set as hidden files.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/sdHxoNvhcB2d9faq8 Here are photos. Only files that open are those I've read (only 80something), but when I go to their file it's empty. Funny thing is - I can search by name, and it works, file appear in search, which ia good, but taking over 300 files one by one will be extremely time consuming

Comment: sorry i'm not sure how it works in windows

Comment: Ah, inderstood! Thank you anyways 